# Delete all created variables in Python IDLE 3.4.0

Tags: python

I would like to know how can I delete the variables created after running a module in Python IDLE, I use del to delete the created variables after I run a module or anything else created on the IDLE window itself. But is there a command that will delete everything from the memory, without restarting the Python IDLE Shell?

Comment: Why do you have the meet? you can reload a model instead.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to turn it off and then back on (restart the interpreter). Why is that unsuitable for you?

Comment: Because I need to import the modules all over again.

Comment: I personally don't use (and don't think I've ever used Idle) but I guess the shell invoked from the tkinter code is a standard Python shell, so you should be able to use the answer I provided.

Answer (score 2):

The dir() can list all the variables in the IDLE, then

```
>>> del VAR_NAME     #can delete that particular variable.
```

This is just to help any newbie happened to be here out of his curiosity.

Comment: So... That would be a really tedious way of doing it, not to mention that you"d have to do one named reference at a time for every single variable created. Sounds like a good job for the `gc` module.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [IPython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/index.html) instead of Python IDLE, you'll have plenty of useful features available, and with *%reset* magic command you can delete all variables and modules previously loaded.

Comment: Thank you I will check it out.

Comment: question was about the standard interpreter. Not all environments have access to IPython.

Answer (score 0):

**You could use the Python Garbage Collector**

```py
import gc
gc.collect()
```